# How do I export Maven Libraries together with my program?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've created a Discord bot in Eclipse and want to export it (Jar file). The problem is: I can't run it. Each time I try to start it it gives me this error:  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/core/entities/Game`

I'm using "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]" for my program.

This here is my pom.xml file
https://pastebin.com/bcs51jm9

After some research it seems like Eclipse doesn't implement the Maven Librarys into the Jar-file.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting a jar with Eclipse from the wizard is generally the way when you don't have a build tool that allows to do it in a straight way.
You use Maven. So you have this tool.

What you need is configuring your pom.xml to enable the [assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) execution with the `jar-with-dependencies` descriptorRef.
It allows to specify the main class and to create a fat jar that contains all required dependencies at runtime according to the Maven dependencies declaration defined in your pom.

By executing `mvn assembly:single` you could so generate an additional jar : a   `jar-with-dependencies`.

Comment: Okay, my pom.xml looks like this now: https://pastebin.com/3ChiRcnL
The file went up to a size of 1.5mb aswell. But I'm still getting the same error. I still need to export it as a normal Jar-file, right?

Comment: Don't use both shade and assembly plugins. These serve a similar goal. Keep the assembly and execute `mvn  assembly:single`.

Comment: Okay. One more dumb question, how and where can I execute `mvn assembly:single´?

Comment: From command line or from Eclipse : "run as Maven build" option from a project.